# Illustrator: how to cut out part of a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

I'm new to Illustrator and, being used to Photoshop, I can't say it's really intuitive. I'm trying to make a logo where part of it is cut out so that the background shows through (see picture below). What's the easiest, most straightforward way to achieve that? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Simple method...

- Convert type to outlines (`Type > Convert to Outlines`)
- Draw a **rectangle** over the area you want to remove
- Select All
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and click-drag across the part(s) to remove.

[image]

You *can* do this *without* converting type to outlines via **Opacity Masks** or **Clipping Masks** but that's an entirely different procedure.

## Clipping Mask...

- Set the type
- Draw **two** rectangles which cover the parts you **want** to show
- Select both rectangles
- Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu
- Select the rectangles *and* the type
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu

Type will still be "live" and editable. Areas *outside* the rectangles are hidden (Masked).

[image]

## Opacity Mask...

- Set type and draw a rectangle over the part to remove
- Select only the rectangle and choose `Edit > Cut` from the menu
- Select the type and on the **Transparency panel** (`Window > Transparency`) Click the **Make Mask** button
- Click the black mask thumbnail and choose `Edit > Paste in Front` from the menu
- **Untick** the `Clip` option
- Click the artwork thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel** to go back to editing the artwork

[image]

To further edit the mask in the future, you need to click the mask thumbnail on the Transparency Panel.

<sub>(Animation done using CS6, so panels may *look* a bit different in more recent versions. However, all the same functionality exists.)</sub>

Comment: What no shapebuilder?

Comment: Did ya miss the first method, @joojaa ? `:)`

Comment: no, you can do same as clipping mask with alt subtract in shapebuilder without expanding. Transparency mask without transparency.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @joojaa Unless they've altered functionality, shapebuilder will *not* allow clipping of live type.

Comment: .. or there's some trick you know I'm unaware of.

Comment: Sorry i mean pathfinder. My bad

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Pathfinder Method :

- Convert type to outlines (`Type > Convert to Outlines`)
- Create a Compound Path (`Object > Compound Path > Create` or `Ctrl+8`)
- Create the rectangle (must be in front of the letter if created before)
- Go to the Pathfinder window and clic on Substract [image: Substract Pathfinder]

And done !
(This method have the same result of using the Shape Builder Tool mentioned by Scott but i wanted to be exhaustive ^^)